# .NET Remoting Serialization Exception : End of Stream Encountered before parsing was completed

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, remoting

My Application calls a little console programm which does the actual connection to a server. This programm also brings Remoting through a Proxy, if the necessary data is passed to it. This worked many times so far but for one customer this program raised this Exception. Nothing is different in the way data is transmitted. The stacktrace tells me, that the Exception was thrown while deserializing the answer from the Server. Also, and even more strange, the console application kind of restarts, going through the Main Method every time this Exception occurs. What is happening here?

Edit:
Sorry for no Code, here everything needed:

```
public static ANFlags LoginWCP(WebProxy wProx = null)
{
    FileLogger.Log("MMLC: LoginWCP");
    MMLC.Register(wProx);
    return MMLC.Login();
}
```

This is the first method getting called by something that want's to connect to the Server.

```
private static void Register(WebProxy iwp = null)
{
FileLogger.Log("MMLC: Register");
try
{
    IDictionary dictionary = new Hashtable();
    if (iwp == null)
    {
        dictionary["useDefaultCredentials"] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        NetworkCredential networkCredential = (NetworkCredential)iwp.Credentials;
        if (networkCredential != null)
        {
            dictionary["domain"] = (networkCredential.Domain ?? null);
            dictionary["password"] = networkCredential.Password;
            dictionary["username"] = networkCredential.UserName;
            dictionary["useDefaultCredentials"] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            dictionary["domain"] = null;
            dictionary["password"] = "1234";
            dictionary["username"] = "m.person";
            dictionary["useDefaultCredentials"] = false;
        }
    }
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    MMLC.HttpChan = new HttpClientChannel(dictionary, new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider());
    MMLC.SetChannelProxy(MMLC.HttpChan, iwp ?? WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy());
    FileLogger.Log("MMLC: RegChannel");
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(MMLC.HttpChan, true);
    MMLC.RemoteObject = (IRemotingObject)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IRemotingObject), "http://x.x.x.x:xxxxx/IRemotingObject");
    FileLogger.Log("MMLC: connected");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("Error connecting to remote server, reason: " + ex.Message);
    MMLC.RemoteObject = null;
}
}
```

This Method does everything that is necessary, to obtain the remoteObject. Those tasks are registering the HttpChannels, setting up the proxy, etc.

Here the SetChannelProxy Method:

```
private static void SetChannelProxy(HttpClientChannel channel, IWebProxy proxy)
{
FieldInfo field = typeof(HttpClientChannel).GetField("_proxyObject", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
field.SetValue(channel, proxy);
}
```

This was required to make the .NET Remoting talk with an proxy.

After the `Register` method, this is called:

```
private static AdminNetworkFlags Login()
{
RSACH rSACH = new RSACH
{
    RSAForeignPubKey = ""
};
MMLC.AESPASS = RSAEH.EncodeToByte(AESThenHMAC.CreatePassword(200, "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@$?_-[](){}=§$%&/"));
byte[] encryptedMessage = null;
try
{
    MMLC.cID = new Guid(MMLC.RemoteObject.Login(rSACH.EncryptB(MMLC.AESPASS), out encryptedMessage)); //this fails
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    FileLogger.LogException(ex);
    throw new Exception("Login Failed!", ex);
}
AdminNetworkFlags result;
try
{
    string text = RSAEH.EncodeToString(AESThenHMAC.SimpleDecryptWithPassword(encryptedMessage, MMLC.AESPASS, 0));
    if (text.Equals("ProtocolVersion4"))
    {
        MMLC.isLoggedIn = true;
        result = AdminNetworkFlags.CLIENTPOS;
    }
    else
    {
        result = AdminNetworkFlags.CLIENTNEG;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex2)
{
    FileLogger.LogException(ex2);
    throw new Exception("Could not decrypt Handshake", ex2);
}
return result;
}
```

Basically, this is some trickery to get encryption without an SSL cert.
All these Methods are in the same class called MMLC.

Here the interface:

```
public interface IRemotingObject
{
    byte[] DoTask(byte[] ID, byte[] Task, byte[] Data, out byte[] reData);

    void Logout(byte[] ID);

    byte[] Login(byte[] Data, out byte[] reData);

    string CallLM(string data);
}
```

And as last thing, the Exception:

```
 System.Exception: Login Failed! ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Das Datenstromende wurde erreicht, bevor die Verarbeitung abgeschlossen wurde. 

 Server stack trace:  
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run() 
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) 
    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) 
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.DeserializeBinaryResponseMessage(Stream inputStream, IMethodCallMessage reqMsg, Boolean bStrictBinding) 
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg) 

 Exception rethrown at [0]:  
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) 
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) 
    at MM.Remoting.Server.IRemotingObject.Login(Byte[] Data, Byte[]& reData) 
    at MM.Remoting.Client.MMLC.Login() 
    --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung --- 
    at MM.Remoting.Client.MMLC.Login() 
    at MM.Remoting.Client.MMLC.LoginWCP(WebProxy wProx) 
    at MMLP.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Is there any chance that Remoting is incompatible to newer kinds of proxies? I thought of that because Remoting is around since .NET 1.0 and got replaced by WCF in .NET 3.0.

Comment: 2 and a half years later, this problem occured once again :(